# iOS Install SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I have a little problem with the new Xcode build for Mac OS X Lion. Here's the situation:

- I run Lion on a separate partition.
  Upgraded Xcode to the most recent,
  iOS 5 compatible version which
  removed my iOS 4 SDK from Lion. I
  didn't ask it to do that, but well,
  it did.
- I still have the iOS 4 SDK on my
  MacBook's built in HD, but dragging
  it into the appropriate folder in
  Lion does not make Xcode recognize
  it.

I need this to run on Mac OS X Lion, but it's not letting me add the iOS 4 SDK again, as I need both iOS 4 and iOS 5 to test on, but am stuck on iOS 5 only.

Has anyone accomplished this yet? Talking nicely to Xcode doesn't seem to help it detect the SDK :( :P

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, Lion and iOS 5 and any beta versions of Xcode are all under NDA. This question should be posted to the beta section of Apple's developer forums.

Comment: However this question is not specific to Lion or iOS5, he could have removed the references to the OSes, but it would have made the question more confusing. This can be applied to Snow Leopard and any 2 different versions of Xcode and SDKs.

Comment: @Jonathan, those products being under NDA, the OP simply shouldn't be asking about them here at this time. As I pointed out, there's a perfectly useable forum for questions pertaining to them, and this isn't it. If the question can legitimately be asked about any two versions of Xcode, then it should be possible to phrase the question clearly without reference to products under NDA.

Comment: @Caleb, the names themselves aren't under NDA, only the features/APIs/etc. If the question was "How do I make my app do *something-new-and-specific-to-Lion/iOS5*?" then the question should be closed. He's only mentioning the names, which are splattered over the Apple website, and on about every tech blog/news site on the internet.

Comment: I haven't mentioned any API's, nor secret features, I'm merely asking about installation. You'll find this stuff all over tech blogs, but that's not what this question is about, so cut the drama. I am well aware of what I can do and what I can't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have installed the latest xcode which included the iOS5 SDK into a seperate directory.

Now you should download the previous version of xcode, the latest one other than the one with iOS5. This will be the one on the Mac App Store, and on the iOS developer site, under the not-beta tab.
Then in the installer choose a different directory, for example "developer-old". This is done on the screen which lists the components that the installer will install. In the middle column there will be a folder icon followed by the word "Developer", click on that, it will produce a dropdown where you can select another directory.

I'm pretty confident this will work, however I installed the Xcode with the iOS5 SDK into a directory named "developer-new", preventing it from overwriting the previous xcode and SDKs.

This also means that you'll have 2 Xcode application, one will only have iOS4, and the other will only have iOS5. You will need to choose which Xcode you use depending on which iOS you are developing for. There will also be 2 iOS simulators.

Comment: Thank you very much. At least one person that has given me a good answer without wasting any time telling me about the NDA which I'm not violating. Thanks!

Comment: @David, I'm glad it helped. I know, the mods/closers here are too trigger happy. As for the problem bring localized it's reasonably common every time a new SDK comes out, where people have overwritten the previous version.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I have not experienced that before, so I was a bit startled but I know how to fix it now. And yep, they are a bit too trigger happy, which sucks.

Comment: Thanks guys for both the question and the answer, this helped me a lot with upgrading from ios 4 to ios 5. I just did a basic ios 5 install and it, much to my surprise, overwrite my ios 4 install. I'm going to try Jonathan's solution and that will hopefully let me run both side by side.